# Articles for fractions of things

Tags: articles, nombres

I'm not sure how to say something like the following in

> The student should speak two thirds (2/3) of the time.

Just going by gut, I would say something

> *L'étudiant devrait parler les deux tiers du temps.*

But this also might be possible or correct:

> *L'étudiant devrait parler deux tiers du temps.*

So do I use the *les* in front of the fraction parts here or not? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you will need the article.

> L'étudiant devrait parler les deux tiers du temps

Note that omitting `les` would be quite understandable, though.

Exception will be if the fraction starts with `un` (one), because it is at the same time a number and also an indefinite article. In this case you have the choice to omit the article *or* to omit the `un`:

> L'étudiant devrait parler un tiers du temps
>
> L'étudiant devrait parler le tiers du temps

(saying *"les un tiers"* would be understandable but quite awkward)